# Deploy simple Spring boot on docker server but getting dockerfile not found error

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have a windows laptop and I have installed a virtual box(Ubuntu OS) with docker installed.I have built a maven spring boot project(myapplication) on my laptop and copied the war generated to the virtual box.
While trying to build the image please find below error encountered  :

[image]

Please find below my Dockerfile content:

```
FROM payara/server-full
COPY myapplication.war $DEPLOY_DIR
```

I was using this on line resource as [tutorial](https://hub.docker.com/r/payara/server-full/)

Please find below my project directory:

[image]

Please note that i am new to docker and anyone can point me what i am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: When you run `docker build` command, it looks for Dockerfile in the current directory and it seems it does there (only WAR file).

Comment: Thanks i did not know that i had to copy the file to the folder i though i will find it in the war

Comment: Did it help? I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the error message can be a little more clear, in essence it means the `docker build` is looking for `Dockerfile` in the current directory and couldn't find it.

Note that `Dockerfile` is only needed during an image build (because it's an instruction on how to build an image) and it doesn't being used later. In other words, you don't need to include `Dockerfile` in WAR file, for example.